# SQL Server : perform an IF test to see if a row exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

`[invoice_lines]`:

```
id (int), customerid (int), price (int), productname (text)
```

I want to query this table, and extract all rows. But I want an additional column which can be a 1/0 column, which checks whether or not there exists a row where productname = 'SLA' AND customerid = customerid.

So lets say I have a row which looks like this:

```
id    customerid    price     productname
-----------------------------------------
 1       134         125      Internet
```

I want this row to be extracted, but I want to see if there is any rows with the productname = 'SLA' AND customerid = '134'. If there is a row which meets these criterias, I want the additional column (lets call it SLA) to have the value 1. If it does not exist, I would like the value to be 0.

Any pointers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by exists?  In the table, for the current invoice, for the current customer?  Is `id` the invoice id or invoice line item id?

Comment: @Dan-Guzman Its the invoice line item id. So basicly I want to check if the customer which has the invoice line "Internet", also has the invoice line "SLA". And if he does, I want the select to echo out "Yes" or "1" in a fifth column. If that customerid does not have a row with the product "SLA", then show "no" or "0".

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*, 
       case when t2.customerid is not null 
            then 1 
            else 0 
       end as result_check
from invoice_lines t1
left join invoice_lines t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid 
                          and t2.productname = 'SLA'
```

Comment: This will multiply the number of rows, if there is more than one match to `SLA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` on your new column which will check that :

```
 select id, customerid,price,productname
    case when productname = 'SLA' and customerid = '134' then 1 else 0 end as SLA
    from [invoice_lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `CROSS APPLY` because joins may produce duplicate rows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName t1
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   *
                                         FROM     TableName t2
                                         WHERE    t2.customerid = t1.customerid AND t2.productname = 'SLA' )
                           THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                      END AS SLA
             ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `exists` in the `select`.  Or, use conditional aggregation with a window function.  This is probably the most efficient method:

```
select il.*, 
       (case when sum(case when productname = 'SLA' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customerid)
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as sla
from invoice_lines il;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all invoice lines in the table, I suggest a CASE expression around a windowing function.  A composite clustered/covering index with a key of customerid and productname to provide the best performance.

```
SELECT  id
      , customerid
      , price
      , productname
      , CASE SUM(CASE WHEN productname = 'SLA' THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                 END) OVER ( PARTITION BY customerid )
          WHEN 0 THEN 0
          ELSE 1
        END AS SLA
FROM    invoice_lines il;
```

A correlated subquery can also do the job but there will probably be a tipping point where the execution plan changes to handle a large number of invoiced lines.

```
SELECT  id
      , customerid
      , price
      , productname
      , CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   *
                           FROM     dbo.invoice_lines b
                           WHERE    b.customerid = a.customerid
                                    AND b.productname = 'SLA' ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS SLA
FROM    dbo.invoice_lines AS a;
```